# Does Adept Dilettante modify an at-will's secondary attack?

Tags: dnd-4e

If a half elf or bard takes riposte strike:

> Riposte Strike
>
> At-Will        Martial, Weapon
>
> Requirement: You must be wielding a light blade.
>
> Target: One creature
>
> Attack: Dexterity vs. AC
>
> Hit: 1[W] + Dexterity modifier damage. If the target attacks you before the start of your next turn and it is within reach, you can make a Strength vs. AC attack against it as an immediate interrupt. On a hit, the target takes 1[W] + Strength modifier damage.

And a feat which modifies a power's attack rolls such as Adept Dilettante:

> Benefit: You can use your Constitution, Wisdom, or Charisma modifier to determine bonuses to attack rolls and damage rolls with the power you chose for your Dilettante racial trait instead of the ability modifier that power normally uses.

or [Combat Virtuoso](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1120):

> Benefit: When you use any attack power gained through a multiclass feat, paragon multiclassing, or the half-elf ’s Dilettante racial feature, you can use Charisma for the power’s attack rolls rather than the ability score normally used to make the attack. You still determine damage normally.

Is the secondary attack's primary stat changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes** (usually)

In the example you give, Riposte Strike's secondary attack is part of the riposte strike power, and so is covered by "attack and damage rolls with the power"... for Adept Dilettante and likewise for Combat Virtuoso.

With a power like the Warden "form" dailies where you gain the use of another power while raging I would probably allow Combat Virtuoso for, but I can see an argument where the "while in a Warden form" power is not gained via a multiclass feat but rather via the Warden form power.

Answer (score 3):

The feats say attack rolls and damage rolls of the gained power, so sure.